# Angular2 - Error with two-way binding: Expression has changed after it was checked

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a simple component to input a text.
But an error has been occured when its value changed.

I have already checked some articles about this error.
One of them said 'Should use enableProdMode()'.
That is certainly true, but I think it's not an essential solution.

Please let me know a nice solution than enableProdMode().

```
@Component({
    selector: 'text-input',
    template: '<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="value"/>',
    inputs: [
        'value'
    ]
})
export class TextInput implements DoCheck {
    @Input() value: string;
    @Output() valueChange: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();

    ngDoCheck(): void {
        console.log(`ngDoCheck: value=${this.value}`);
        this.valueChange.emit(this.value);
    }
}
```

-

```
@Component({
    template: `
        <h1>Input Components</h1>
        <h2>Text Input</h2>
        <div>
           <text-input [(value)]='textValue'></text-input>
        </div>
        <div>{{textValue}}</div>`
})
export class InputsPage {
    textValue: string = 'Hello World';
}
```

Comment: I think you just need to remove the parantheses from the input like so: `<text-input [value]="textvalue"></text-input>`. I think the error occurs because there should be no two-way-databinding.

Comment: @alexkucksdorf The point here is the twoway binding to be able to notify the parent when change happens in child. So twoway binding is needed here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use `DoCheck` for this, if you just want to inform the parent when a change has happened, use `ngModelChange` instead and emit the value. So add `ngModelChange`

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="value" (ngModelChange)="emitValue()"/>

@Input() value: string;
@Output() valueChange: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();

emitValue(): void {
    this.valueChange.emit(this.value);
}
```

And you should be all good! Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your advice. It works well for me. That was great help!!

Comment: You are welcome, glad to help! :) If this answer solved your issue, would you mind accepting this answer by clicking the grey tick under the voting of the answer, here's closer details how to do that: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235 :)

Comment: I'm sorry that I haven't understood the rule. I clicked it out to mark as it's been closed. Thank you for telling me how to behave on stackoverflow.

Comment: Absolutely no problem. it's not a demanded action, but it marks the question and problem as solved, for other people to know. But thanks and happy coding! :)